# How to pass a method to string attribute of a child Component

Tags: vuejs3, vue-props

I have a Component with the following attribute.

```
<script>
  export default {
    props: {
      iconColor: {type: String, default: "currentColor"}
    },
  };
</script>
```

This attribute can be changed from outside by using a Slot.

```
...
<g :fill="iconColor"><slot /></g>
```

I've createad a method that returns the rgba-code of a color based on a color name:

```
methods: {
  colorLookup(status) {
    switch(status): {
      case "green": return "rgba(0,230,64,1)";
      case "yellow": return "rgba(240,255,0,1)";
      case "red": return "rgba(217,30,24,1)";
    }
  }
}
```

My problem is that I can't pass this method to the `iconColor` attribute.

Passing `iconColor="rgba(0,230,64,1)"` works, but passing `iconColor="{{colorLookup(status)}}"` doesn't.

I've tested the method in an `<td>`-element and the method delivers the needed `String`.

How do we do this in `Vue3`??

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: it should be like `[iconColor]="colorLookup(status)"`

Comment: Thank you so much for you quick response. Unfortunately this doesn't work and throws an error: `Failed to execute setAttribute on Element: [iconColor] is not a valid attribute name`.

Comment: sorry, by bad.. it should be `:iconColor="colorLookup(status)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `v-bind` to bind to dynamic value

```
v-bind:iconColor="colorLookup(status)"
```

or you can use shorthand

```
:iconColor="colorLookup(status)"
```